# Nx React - Assets can't be resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, webpack, monorepo

I'm working on a nx monorepo that has a few library and 2 apps.

### File Structures

apps
\--api
\--funnel ( react with webpack )
\--api-e2e
\--funnel-e2e
libs
\--funnel
\----pages
\--shared
\----assets
\-------src
\--------lib
\----------'some .tsx assets' ( lottie files )
\--------assets
\----------images
\-------------**/*.(png|webp|gif|svg) ( all others assets )

## What's expected

In my libraries and in my app, I'd like to use the assets as such:
`import imageName from '/assets/images/<some-image-folder>/<some-image-name>.<ext>';`

For all svg, png, jpeg, etc...

for svgs: 
`import { ReactComponent from imageName } from '/assets/images/<some-image-folder>/<some-image-name>.svg';`

## Issue

My actual issues is that when i'm building the funnel app nx run funnel:build --verbose

my assets seems to be loaded into the cache but every assets return a : Module not found: `Error: Can't resolve '/assets/images/<some-image-folder>/<some-image-name>.<ext>' from '<whatever-lib>/<main-app>'`

Yes i use /assets/images As i'm using angular functionaility to "serve" the assets to `/assets/images`

## What is my config

**#NX Report**

Node : 16.16.0 OS   : darwin x64 npm  : 9.2.0

nx : 15.6.0 
@nrwl/angular : Not Found 
@nrwl/cypress : 15.6.0
 @nrwl/detox : Not Found
 @nrwl/devkit : 15.6.0 
@nrwl/esbuild : Not Found 
@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 15.6.0 
@nrwl/expo : Not Found
 @nrwl/express : 15.6.3
 @nrwl/jest : 15.6.0
 @nrwl/js : 15.6.0
 @nrwl/linter : 15.6.0 
@nrwl/nest : Not Found
 @nrwl/next : Not Found
 @nrwl/node : 15.6.3
 @nrwl/nx-cloud : 15.0.3 
@nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
 @nrwl/react : 15.6.0
 @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
 @nrwl/rollup : Not Found
 @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
 @nrwl/storybook : Not Found 
@nrwl/web : Not Found 
@nrwl/webpack : 15.6.3
 @nrwl/workspace : 15.6.0
 @nrwl/vite : Not Found 
typescript : 4.8.4

**#app/funnel/project.json**

My assets are imported through the main app as i don't build any of the sub-lib here's the selector :

```json
{  
   "input": "libs/shared/assets/src/assets/images",
   "glob": "**/*",  
   "output": "assets/images"
}
```

**#app/funnel/webpack.config.js**

Couldn't import the whole code due to StackOverflow error but, in simple terms i added svgr support, file-loader & url-loader

```js
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(webp|png|gif|jpe?g)$/i
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            '@svgr/webpack',
            'url-loader'
          ]
        }
      ],
}
```

## Explanation of what I've tried so far

**#1rst attempt**
I used the angular functionality to import assets on build such as shown on the top config with the selector.

**#2nd attempt**
I used copy-webpack-plugin to copy static assets to '/assets/' without success

**#3rd attempt**
I added a path to the main tsconfig.base.json `"@myapp/assets/*"` : `["libs/shared/assets/src/assets/**/*"]`

and tried to serve the assets as such : "@myapp/assets//."

**#4rth attempt**

The solution that works but isn't optimized for my workflow is to put each asset next to its dependencies...

This is disgusting as I need to duplicate assets, which are subject to a lot of changes.

## Please help.

Here's the small-sized test repo : https://github.com/Sosumappu/assets-monorepo-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your project it is not an asset pb, but an issue with loading svg images

I  managed to load it .

At first upgrade your nx project from nx 15.6.0 to nx 15.6.3 :
npx nx migrate latest

You made a mistake, replace apple-pay.svg with applepay.svg  in your project

change the color of your svg file to red, we can not see it (white on white background).

edit webpack.config.js as follow :

```
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nrwl/webpack');
const { withReact } = require('@nrwl/react');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(
  withNx({
    nx: {
      svgr: true,
    },
  }),
  withReact({ svgr: true }),
  (config) => {
 
    return config;
  }
);
```

shared-ui.tsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

//Static Import
import Logo from '@github-test/shared/assets';
export const ApplePayIcon = () => {
  return <Logo />;
};
```

libs/shared/assets/src/index.ts :

```
import Logo from '-!@svgr/webpack!./assets/images/applepay.svg';
export default Logo;
```

here you can console.log(Logo), you will see it is creating a react component

Comment: Hello, So I indeed followed this recipe as many others such as https://juristr.com/blog/2020/05/nx-libs-with-assets/ or this https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/208... A nice point is that while create the test monorepo I got more information on the error tho I don't know how to fix it. Here's the repo : https://github.com/Sosumappu/assets-monorepo-test. you can get the error on `npx nx build git-test -verbose`. Thanks for you help concerning the /assets/ you might be right as i've seen different kinds of error depending on the "./assets/" or "/assets/

Comment: I managed to load it.

Comment: It does work well, on my main project but for some reason those imports aren't can't be styled, aswell i have around 200 assets, pngs included gaves thoses errors shall i use the assets library as a shell to export them all ? It's quite tedius tho to import export all svgs... If you have a workaround would be great

Comment: There is no problem using jpg or png in a library . you can give it a try. unfortunately for unknown reason at the moment for svg  I have not found any other solution .  may be try some plugin like react svg loader. or  switch to vite build with vite copy plugin .

Comment: I did the above setup you've shown for my 250~assets and it worked thanks a lot !